# Laravel - Unhandled exception error

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables - members and topics. The two tables are related to each other by one to many relationship as follows:

```
class Topic extends Eloquent 
{
     public function member()
     {
           return $this->belongs_to('Member');
     }
 }

class Member extends Eloquent 
{
     public function topics() 
     {
         return $this->has_many('Topic');
     }
}
```

I get an `Unhandled Exception error - Trying to get property of non-object` when I try something like this:

```
$members = Topic::find(1)->member->get()->email;
```

Where am I going wrong? There seems to be no problem with data consistency in DB.

Comment: try `$email = Topic::find(1)->member()->get()->email;`

Comment: I assume this is Laravel 3, not Laravel 4...?

Comment: Try `Topic::find(1)->member()->first()->email` or `Topic::find(1)->member->email`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have standard naming of the foreign key field?  The field name in the member table should be topic_id.  If it's not, you'll want to define member() as

```
return $this->belongs_to("Member","fkfieldname");
```

(Also, if you're using Laravel4, you'll want to use belongsTo() instead of belongs_to().)

Answer (score 0):

The function member in your Topic model, returns an array.

The correct way to access the foreign relation would be

$members = Topic::find(1)->member[0]->email